# Does Guns of Icarus game have an ending?

Tags: guns-of-icarus

I was playing [Guns of Icarus](http://store.steampowered.com/app/49800/) and followed a route all the way to the "Into The Breach" level. But that level seems to be a never-ending survival one.

Is there any way to actually finish the game? Is there any ending of some sort?

[image: Game map showing all possible routes (levels), and showing my route (following the easiest path) to the final level.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps unfortunately, there is not an ending to the story. I have played the game, and Into the Breach is meant to be the final apocalyptic mission. It's your suicide mission into the pirates, and does not end until you die; you just try to accumulate a high score.

If you're looking for references, [this review](http://www.ztgd.com/reviews/8955/guns-of-icarus/) calls Into the Breach "survival mode" which is just what I have described above. This survival mission is also the end goal of the game. Everything else is just a build up to upgrade your ship in preparation.